# Как сделать массив?

Tags: php, массивы

Ребят, подскажите, вот у меня есть форма, в нее вводятся значения, кажое значения с новой строки. Например:
Вася
Петя
Коля
Дима

Как из этих значений, сделать массив?

Comment: Блин, в одну строку все написалось, каждое имя с новой строки.

Comment: Вы можете отредактировать свое сообщение

Comment: Под сообщением нажмите "править" для редактирования своего сообщения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для разбиения строки по определенному символу используйте функцию [explode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php). А для зачистки строк уже в массиве можно использовать [trim()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.trim.php) через [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php).

**Например:**

```
<?php

// строка с переносами строк из POST запроса
$string = "Вася
Петя
Коля
Дима";

// Разбиваем на массив по знаку переноса строки и чистим края слов
$array = array_map("trim", explode("\n", $string));

var_dump($array); // выводим на экран для проверки
```

**Результат:**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "Вася"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "Петя"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "Коля"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "Дима"
}
```

Comment: Да, большое спасибо, все работает.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Принимаем строку
$var = $_POST['name'];
// Разбиваем по символу переноса строки на массив
$array = explode("\n", $var);
```

Готово! $array - ваш массив имён

Comment: Все равно в 0 все кидает

Answer (score 0):

Для этого используйте ф-ю [**explode**](http://www.php.su/explode()):

```
$array = explode(' ', $form_data);
```